# Does Requirejs 2.0 and jQuery with Plugins using ShimConfig need paths?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs

I'm using requirejs 2.x and loading jQuery fromt he CDN and a backup in a local file. I'm trying to load the jQuery plugins with the shim config solution. This seems to work fine on fast connection and local browsers, however when I've tested through wireless or slow connections, I seem to get random errors where the plugins are looking for jquery and it hasn't loaded yet.  although I've been through docs and other sites relating to this issue, the setup looks fine.

Below is a sample.

```
// main.js    
requirejs.config({
   baseUrl: "scripts",
   paths: {
      "jquery" : [
         "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min",
         "libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min"
      ],
      "$plugins":"./libs/jquery",
      "modules" : "./app/modules",
   },
   shim: {
      "jquery.easing" : ["jquery"],
      "jquery.urlutils": ["jquery"]
   },
   priority: ["jquery"]
});

// somemodule.js
define([
   'modules/otherModule',
   'jquery',
   '$plugins/jquery.urlutils'
], function( OtherModule, $ ) {
   // code...
});
```

Here we can see that 'somemodule' is loading jQuery and otherModule ( works fine ). jquery on the other hand loads only sometimes before the plugin.  I've tried adding the plugin to the paths object with a direct path then in the 'somemodule' above omit the $plugins path.  this seems to setup fine everytime.  But doesn't this defeat the purpose of the shim?  Don't like the fact that I have to setup the path and set it's dependencies.

Any help would be appreciated.  it's driving me nuts. :)

Am I missing something?  or do I need to prefix the shim key with the $plugins path before the jquery plugin?

### Possible solution

I have found a solution...I believe; I'm still testing to confirm cross-browser.

Note the path of the jquery plugin (jquery.urlutils) in the shim and the define dependency list in the 'somemodule'. Also note that I'm using a path to direct to the actual location to the plugin.

Also note that I didn't end up using 'enforeDefine', if I do, I recieve the error once again and/or a 'define does not exists' error.

```
requirejs.config({
   baseUrl: "scripts",
   paths: {
      "jquery" : [
         "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min",
         "libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min"
      ],
      "$plugins":"./libs/jquery",
      "modules" : "./app/modules",
   },
   shim: {
      "$plugins/jquery.easing" : ["jquery"],
      "$plugins/jquery.urlutils": ["jquery"]
   },
   priority: ["jquery"]
});

// somemodule.js
define([
   'modules/otherModule',
   'jquery',
   '$plugins/jquery.urlutils'
], function(OtherModule, $ ) {
   // code...
});
```

Comment: Any luck with this yet ??
I'm having the same exact problem, and the funny thing is it happens randomly..

Answer (score 0):

I am actually reading through the entire RequireJS 2.0 documentation right now, and came across what I think will solve your problem.

You need to set `enforceDefine` to `true` in require config, like so:

```
requirejs.config({
    //To get timely, correct error triggers in IE, force a define/shim exports check.
    enforceDefine: true,
})
```

This forces require to `undef()` the model on error, and wait for the model to be defined properly before continuing. Read about it [here](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0#wiki-ieloadfail)

Upon further reading of the documentation, it appears you must also set the `exports` value to the return value of the included script, so that require has a variable it can check to see if the load was sucessful. Add jquery and jquery-ui to your shim.

```
shim: {
    "jquery": {
        exports: "jQuery"
    },
    "jquery-ui": {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: "jQuery.ui"
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not helping. I'm still receiving a 'ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined' on my script when loading through require.  I've also tried variations of paths throughout the shim and paths config, with and without 'enforceDefine'.

Comment: The order of your define array does not match the order of the arguments you expect. Shouldn't it be `function( OtherModule, $ )`?

Comment: Two things to your edit above:  1. jquery should not have to be shimmed as it has a define call ( other have also posted this ), though, I'll try this with just the exports value and see what comes up, thanks.   2. some of my plugins for jQuery have multiple added functions (i.e. $.fn.doThis & $.fn.doThat - as part of the plugin ), would I just use one - for the check of load?

Comment: Austin -yes your right, typo, however, above is sample-pseudo code derived from my actual code.

Comment: possible answer in my original post.  Any other ideas/help are welcome.  thanks.

Comment: Hm I'm at a bit of a dead end here. However, I am not familiar with the `priority` option. Could you provide a link that explains it more?