# Load jquery from CDN with fallback on optimized requireJS

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I want to load jquery from a CDN with a local fallback.

That's pretty straightforward if you look it up in stackoverflow, i found this [informative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143737/does-requirejs-2-0-and-jquery-with-plugins-using-shimconfig-need-paths) about the task.

But when I am optimizing the code for production, jQuery gets bundled inside the optimized code, which kind of defeats the purpose of loading jQuery via a public CDN.

What are the solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way might be to exclude it from your build. Use the config option `exclude`

https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L352